# Python subprocess: pass non-string to argument

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I am using Raspberry Pi to record audio. I tried pyaudio but it didn't work, then I tried to use the subprocess module. As the recording needs to be executed multiple times, I need to make sure that the recoding filename is different after every recording.

For example, I would like to:

```
filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")+".wav"
```

My question is: can I pass this filename as an argument to subprocess? I checked the document, it says only string and list are supported as arguments in subprocess.

Comment: Well, isn't a filename a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filename *is* a string. So nothing prevents it from being used as one of the strings in subprocess.

Take care to use the list of strings variant with `shell=False` (the default) and the string variant with `shell=True`. Then everything should work as needed.